# About .dojoxGridMasterHeader { display:none; }

Tags: datagrid, header, dojo

I am using a dojo dataGrid to render a table. I need to hide the header row.

The Dojo documentation recommended using .dojoxGrid-header { display:none; } to turn off the column header but I only saw dojoxGridMasterHeader  used in the debugger.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#hiding-the-headers-of-a-grid

In order to hide the dojo dataGrid's header row, I defined this in the HTML file.

```
.dojoxGridMasterHeader { display:none; }
```

I loaded the dojo library first, and then my own CSS style.

```
<style type="text/css">
.dojoxGridMasterHeader { display:none; }
</style>
```

However, the UI still displays the header in the dataGrid.  The debugger shows this code for the header

I don't understand why the CSS still go overwritten to style="display: block"

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!important`

```
.dojoxGridMasterHeader {
     display: none !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/Uy3nQ/